# Is there any way to edit an html file from another one, with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to add some code inside another html file with javascript like

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML
```

Comment: Let's suppose you have two html files: `a.html` and `b.html`. Inside `a.html` do you want to write some JavaScript code that modify the html in `b.html`? Is this your question?

Comment: There is a huge difference bettween editing a html file, and adding content inside it inside the page itself. What do you want? If you want to add more elements, texts to your page, see biancamihai's answer, if you want to edit the content of the file located in your hard disk, you can't do that with JS.

Comment: I am not sure what you want? I believe you should answer @Andrea reply... The question is not clear at all...

Comment: @Andrea yes this is my qustion

Answer (score 1):

yes it is, take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

```
// Create a new paragraph element, and append it to the end of the document body
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(p);
```